# not able to logout from facebook using facebook c# sdk

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I am Using facebook C# SDK to connect to facebook from my mvc3 application.
I am able to login but not able to logout.
I used bellow code for logout

```
var oauth = new FacebookClient();

        var logoutParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
              {
                  { "next", "http://localhost:8691" }
              };

        var logoutUrl = oauth.GetLogoutUrl(logoutParameters);

        return Redirect(logoutUrl.ToString());
```

This code always redirects me to facebook home page.

Comment: What is the value of `logoutParameters` and post te code that handles the login procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it.
I just passed access token in logoutParameters.

Here is my action result code.

```
        public ActionResult LogOut(string accessToken)
    {
        var oauth = new FacebookClient();

        var logoutParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
              {
                 {"access_token", accessToken},
                  { "next", "http://localhost:8691" }
              };

        var logoutUrl = oauth.GetLogoutUrl(logoutParameters);

        return Redirect(logoutUrl.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [Link](http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started), they suggest to handle all log in\log off with the javascript sdk for FB.